# Dimensão de um display - Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, display

Estou fazendo uns testes com uma imagem no Android utilizando a classe Canvas. Estou utilizando um Samsung Galaxy Mini S3 e um Samsung Galaxy S2.

Fisicamente os aparelhos são diferentes (a tela do S2 é maior), mas os retornos dos métodos abaixo são os mesmos:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
width = size.x;
height = size.y;
```

Para ambos os aparelhos, a altura (height) é 800px e a largura (width) 480px (em portrait). Como o S2 é maior, eu achei que os valores não seriam iguais.

Existe alguma padronização para o tamanho do display dos smartphones? Será que a maioria é esse padrão, 800 por 480 (ou pelo menos será que a maioria utiliza esta proporção)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem bem um padrão. Android pode ser utilizado em tablets, smarthphones, relógios, TVs e etc. Cada fabricante adapta o sistema para o aparelho de acordo com as necessidades e propostas do mesmo.

O que você pode fazer é desenvolver focando-se nas dimensões mais populares e projetar pensando em `dp` ao invés de `px`.

No seu caso, você testou em dois dispositivos que tem telas de dimensões físicas diferentes, mas possuem resoluções iguais. Por isso, o que você deve considerar em seu projeto é a densidade de pixels.

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 // Verifique metrics.
```

Confira esse [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) para mais detalhes.

---

Sobre o uso de imagem, você possivelmente terá que disponibilizar no seu apk versões diferentes para cada densidade de pixels (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi).